# A single word that describes or connotes all items in a list except the last item

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe all the elements in a list, **except the last** item?

The *head* of a list refers to the first item in the list and the *tail* refers to the last item. In mathematics and computer science, the tail can also refer to all the elements after the first; I'm not sure if that carries over into other domains.

(chatGPT suggested "penultimates", which made me chuckle)

Comment: I know of a word that means every item in the list except the second one. With some math you could probably adapt it.

Comment: Consider [this example context,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22penultimate+string+of+digits+An+affirmative%22) referring to a ***penultimate string of digits*** of arbitrary size (up to and including *all* digits preceding the final one). I'm not gonna try to understand the full context, but it seems quite possible if a couple of mathematicians were discussing the matter, they might very quickly establish "a penultimate" as short for "a penultimate string of digits". And maybe for their purposes, the *maximum length* one is the "archetype", so the single word means *exactly* that.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be the compound word *non-final*.

The most common usage of non-final is in the context of some kind of transitionary state, or interim decision. However, both Collins and OED also have

> [...] *that which does not fall at the end of a word or series*

...particularly in the domain of linguistics terminology.

Interestingly, both Cambridge and Merriam-Webster have a broader definition along the lines of

> *not last, or not at the end of something*

without referring to the domain of linguistics, but then in both cases give example usages that appear to come from that domain. ("In this language, the verb is rarely in a non-final position"; "*nonfinal* syllables")

Comment: non-final means all except the last in a list? I really don't think so.